# Filter the nodes by language output by the view

Tags: views

Before I have i18n module and some modules that does the translations but we decided to stop doing translation but still preserve the translated nodes.

After disabling translation modules my views which are using **content negotiation** says "Broken/Invalid handler" so I removed this filter.

Now all the views are using nodequeue which has a bunch of multilingual nodes.

My question is, how can I filter views to display nodes based on page language. I mean I want to display english articles only when I'm in English pages, korean articles when viewing Korean pages, japanese articles when viewing Japanese pages, etc.

Ex. nodes(eng) for English pages, nodes(korean) for Korean pages, nodes(japanese) for Japanese pages, and nodes(chinese) when in Chinese pages

Answer (score 0):

one work around is to re-enable the i18n module, to access the filter again, then use some hooks ( like hook_form) to hide and set the default values for the i18n options in the node form if you want to remove those options from the user interface.